# .htaccess PHP 5.3 option breaks Access-Control-Allow-Origin option?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Let me first say that I am running on a shared linux server with HostGator.

My problem is I had this line of code in my .htaccess:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

Which allowed cross-domain xhr requests. It was working find till my hosting provider told me to add this to get php 5.3 (which my program requires):

```
# Use PHP 5.3
Action application/x-hg-php53 /cgi-sys/php53
AddHandler application/x-hg-php53 .php
```

Now I can no longer make cross-domain xhr requests. Does anyone know why this no longer works? (I do get PHP 5.3 though)

** **Update** **

Well, it looks like it's something that's not my fault and something I can't fix. Here's the official response from HostGator Tech Support:

> I've examined your site, the error logs, and the .htaccess directives,
>   and unfortunately I've come to the conclusion that the "Header set
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin *" line is not compatible with our
>   implementation of PHP 5.3 as found in our shared servers. I sincerely
>   apologize for the inconvenience that this causes, but the way we
>   implement and call PHP 5.3 (since 5.2 is the default and cannot be
>   altered thanks to cPanel) apparently overrides the Header handling
>   mechanism, making it not work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *should* work both together, however, if you want to provide an endpoint with that header explicitly set, you can do it with PHP as well:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Put it into your PHP code before any output starts. See [`header`](http://php.net/header).

Comment: i don't really have that option. It needs to be set in the .htaccess to work on ALL calls.

Comment: Well at least for all PHP calls you can do it that way. If that's what you want to say with your comment. Otherwise, you should not have any problem to configure your apache server to set the header for you as well: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header - if that directive does not work, you can use mod_rewrite as well to set headers, but actually it should work. No idea what has been configured with your server that it doesn't. Maybe you need to post your whole .htaccess.

Comment: I've tried this just to see if I could get this to work, but For some reason it doesn't. When I make a call to the same domain, I get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header correctly, but the call to the different domain still returns the error. Both domains point to the same thing.

Comment: Scratch that, I placed it in a different file and now it works.

Comment: Set the header with PHP then you don't need to care about server configuration. Just put it into every file in question. Works on any host.

Comment: I put it in the bootstrap of the application, but needing to remember to put it in the bootstrap of EVERY application on the server seemed a bit much and unnecessary, but since I have no other option...